# How do I get power from gaussian beam numerically?

Tags: numerics

I would like to get the power from a Gaussian beam given a set of points at which electric field is evaluated. Please follow my reasoning and tell me what assumption maybe are wrong

Power definition is:

$ P = \int |E|^2dA$

We integrate over area, then Power is a quantity that does not depend on the geometry. If we compute the integral over a cross section of a Gaussian Beam or over the spherical surface, both results should be the same (I think ??)

To test so, I wrote a code to get the electric field on both regions (code below), and I'm here looking for help of how to integrate electric field on both scenarios.

### Gaussian Electric Field

I'm using expression (3.11) from this [pdf](https://www.photonics.ethz.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/Courses/NanoOptics/focus3.pdf) and not changing the direction of propagation, it is a Gaussian beam of waist $w_0$ traveling at $\hat{z}$ direction

### Cross Section

Looking at Stackoverflow [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567166/uniformly-distribute-x-points-inside-a-circle) I am using Sunflower Seed Arrangements with radius equal to the Gaussian waist

### Sphere

Nothing special, I have matrix of points uniformly distributed in $\theta$ and $\phi$ spherical coordinates.

Now, my source code wrote in Julia language :

```
using Plots
plotly()

function E_gaussian(x,y,z, k₀, w₀, E₀)
    first_term = exp(im*k₀*z)/(1 + 2*im*z/(k₀*w₀^2))
    second_term = exp(  - ((x^2 + y^2)/w₀^2)*(1/(1 + 2*im*z/(k₀*w₀^2)))  )
    E = E₀*first_term*second_term
    return E
end

function createGaussianSection(nPoints, α, w₀ )
    b = round(α*sqrt(nPoints)) # number of boundary points
    ϕ = (sqrt(5)+1)/2 # golden ratio
    screen = zeros(nPoints,3)
    for k=1:nPoints
        r = radius_sunflower(k,nPoints,b)
        θ = 2*pi*k/ϕ^2
        screen[k,1] = w₀*r*cos(θ)
        screen[k,2] = w₀*r*sin(θ)
        screen[k,3] = 0
    end
    return screen
end

function radius_sunflower(k,n,b)
    if k>n-b
        r = 1 # put on the boundary
    else
        r = sqrt(k-1/2)/sqrt(n-(b+1)/2) # apply square root
    end
    return r
end

function getE_GassianSection(screen, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
    nPoints = size(screen,1)
    E_laser = zeros(Complex{Float64}, nPoints )

    for k =1:nPoints
        xₛ = screen[k,1]
        yₛ = screen[k,2]
        zₛ = screen[k,3]
        E_laser[k] = E_gaussian(xₛ, yₛ, zₛ, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
    end
    return E_laser
end



function createSphere(Radius, θNintervals, φNintervals, w₀, k₀)
    θ_range = range(0, stop=π, length=θNintervals)
    φ_range = range(0, stop=2π, length=φNintervals)

    xₛ = Radius.*[cos(φ)*sin(θ) for θ in θ_range, φ in φ_range]
    yₛ = Radius.*[sin(φ)*sin(θ) for θ in θ_range, φ in φ_range]
    zₛ = Radius.*[cos(θ) for θ in θ_range, φ in φ_range]

    screen = zeros(size(xₛ,1),size(xₛ,2),3)
    screen[:,:,1] = xₛ
    screen[:,:,2] = yₛ
    screen[:,:,3] = zₛ

    return screen, θ_range, φ_range
end


function getE_Sphere(screen, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
    nΘ = size(screen,1)
    nΦ = size(screen,2)
    E_sphere = zeros(Complex{Float64},nΘ, nΦ )

    for θ in 1:nΘ, φ in 1:nΦ
        xₛ = screen[θ,φ,1]
        yₛ = screen[θ,φ,2]
        zₛ = screen[θ,φ,3]
        E_sphere[θ,φ] = E_gaussian(xₛ, yₛ, zₛ, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
    end
    return E_sphere
end

k₀ =  1
w₀ = 30/k₀
E₀ = 1

screenGaussin = createGaussianSection(5000, 0, w₀)
E_section = getE_GassianSection(screenGaussin, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
Intensity_section = real.( conj.(E_section).*E_section)
scatter(screenGaussin[:,1], screenGaussin[:,2], zcolor=Intensity_section, axis=:equal, label="", xlabel="x", ylabel="y")



Radius = 50/k₀
θNintervals = φNintervals = 25
screen, θ_range, φ_range = createSphere(Radius, θNintervals, φNintervals, w₀, k₀)
E_sphere = getE_Sphere(screen, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
Intensity_sphere = real.( conj.(E_sphere).*E_sphere)
scatter3d(screen[:,:,1],screen[:,:,2],screen[:,:,3], zcolor =Intensity_sphere , label="")
```

The results are the following, the color is the local intensity:
[image]
[image]

From everything that I've shown, I only have **Points**. How do I find **Areas** and *integrate* them ???

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for people on inbox to help me.

1. I don't need full sphere, only half of sphere contains the same energy of the cross section.
2. I can use my point grid and imagine a small area between them. I set a point and create a square based upon the nearest neighbors.

   2.1 In spherical coordinates, an element of area is $dA = r^2sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$. To covert this expression into discrete case, we use $d\theta = \theta[i+1]-\theta[i]$ and $d\phi= \phi[i+1]-\phi[i]$, and also $\theta$ is the average of the nearest neighbors $\theta = (\theta[i+1]+\theta[i])/2$

   2.2 For simplicity, the cross section area can be just a square grid of points
3. This procedure works only for far field, that is, the radius of the sphere should be big if compared with the Gaussian waist ( I've used a wrong choice of values in my example)

For everybody that is interested, here the full working code:

```
function E_gaussian(x,y,z, k₀, w₀, E₀)
    first_term = exp(im*k₀*z)/(1 + 2*im*z/(k₀*w₀^2))
    second_term = exp(  - ((x^2 + y^2)/w₀^2)*(1/(1 + 2*im*z/(k₀*w₀^2)))  )
    E = E₀*first_term*second_term
    return E
end

function createGaussianSection(nPoints, w₀ )
    x_range = range(-w₀, stop=w₀, length=nPoints)
    y_range = range(-w₀, stop=w₀, length=nPoints)
    screen = zeros(nPoints, nPoints, 3)
    screen[:,:,1] = [x for x in x_range, y in y_range]
    screen[:,:,2] = [y for x in x_range, y in y_range]
    screen[:,:,3] .= 0
    return screen, x_range, y_range
end



function createSphere(Radius, θNintervals, φNintervals, w₀, k₀)
    θ_range = range(0, stop=π/2, length=θNintervals)
    φ_range = range(0, stop=2π, length=φNintervals)

    xₛ = Radius.*[cos(φ)*sin(θ) for θ in θ_range, φ in φ_range]
    yₛ = Radius.*[sin(φ)*sin(θ) for θ in θ_range, φ in φ_range]
    zₛ = Radius.*[cos(θ) for θ in θ_range, φ in φ_range]

    screen = zeros(size(xₛ,1),size(xₛ,2),3)
    screen[:,:,1] = xₛ
    screen[:,:,2] = yₛ
    screen[:,:,3] = zₛ

    return screen, θ_range, φ_range
end


function getE(screen, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
    nΘ = size(screen,1)
    nΦ = size(screen,2)
    E_sphere = zeros(Complex{Float64},nΘ, nΦ )

    for θ in 1:nΘ, φ in 1:nΦ
        xₛ = screen[θ,φ,1]
        yₛ = screen[θ,φ,2]
        zₛ = screen[θ,φ,3]
        E_sphere[θ,φ] = E_gaussian(xₛ, yₛ, zₛ, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
    end
    return E_sphere
end

k₀ =  1
w₀ = 30/k₀
E₀ = 1


screenGaussin, x_range, y_range = createGaussianSection(150, 2*w₀)
E_section = getE(screenGaussin, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
Intensity_section = real.( conj.(E_section).*E_section)

I_section = 0
for x = 1:(length(x_range)-1), y = 1:(length(y_range)-1)
    global I_section
    E_mean = (E_section[x, y] + E_section[x+1, y] + E_section[x, y+1]+E_section[x+1, y+1])/4
    ΔA = (x_range[x+1]-x_range[x])*(y_range[y+1]-y_range[y])
    I_section += real(conj(E_mean)*E_mean)*ΔA
end
println("Total Power Section: ", round(I_section,digits=3))


Radius = 1000/k₀
θNintervals = φNintervals = 200
screen, θ_range, φ_range = createSphere(Radius, θNintervals, φNintervals, w₀, k₀)
E_sphere = getE(screen, k₀,  w₀, E₀)
Intensity_sphere = real.( conj.(E_sphere).*E_sphere)

I_sphere = 0
for θ = 1:(θNintervals-1), φ = 1:(φNintervals-1)
    global I_sphere
    E_medio = (E_sphere[θ, φ] + E_sphere[θ+1, φ] + E_sphere[θ, φ+1]+E_sphere[θ+1, φ+1])/4
    ΔA = (Radius^2)*sin(   (θ_range[θ]+θ_range[θ+1])/2  )*(θ_range[θ+1]-θ_range[θ])*(φ_range[φ+1]-φ_range[φ])
    I_sphere += real(conj(E_medio)*E_medio)*ΔA
end
println("Total Power Sphere: ", round(I_sphere,digits=3))

println("Relation:",round(I_section/I_sphere,digits=3))
```

Results:

```
Total Power Section: 1413.028
Total Power Sphere: 1413.567
Relation:1.0
```